# Eclipse won't run Android app on device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to run an android app from Eclipse on my device. It is an HTC Android Incredible.

However, whenever I try to run it, this error pops up.

```
[2013-01-27 21:46:54 - PowerSourceInternational] Failed to install PowerSourceInternational.apk on      device 'HT0CDHJ08446': Read-only file system
[2013-01-27 21:46:54 - PowerSourceInternational] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Read-only file system
[2013-01-27 21:46:54 - PowerSourceInternational] Launch canceled!
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if there is enough space on the device. I also assume you have tried turning it off and on again. If not, do that.

Comment: check this link.might help you   http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33959

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is needing to turn on the ability to install apps via *Unknown sources*; `Settings -> Application -> Unknown sources`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to place where adb is placed and try this

adb shell sysrw

adb push your_app

adb shell sync

adb shell sysro

Comment: For those who get the error "/system/bin/sh: sysrw: not found", that is because sysrw is actually a script that you need to create yourself, but I don't know where that is.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by calling adb kill-server, then restart the device, then run from your development environment (in my case Eclipse) in the usual fashion.